# Quando e como usar o @Value Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

Ola!
Estou fazendo a validação de vulnerabilidades apontadas pelo SonarQube em uma API, e o Sonar apresentou o seguinte problema para as variáveis e objetos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com  a seguinte sugestão para estes trechos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Além disso, qual a notação correta para ser usada? Estou usando o @Value, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada uma dessas anotações tem uma função diferente, o @Autowired por exemplo é usado pelo spring para criar e injetar instâncias de classes que você anotou com @Service, @Component, @Repository ou @Bean. Ou seja, você não precisar dar new na classe, o spring fará isso pra você.

Sobre o @Value, ele serve para que você possa capturar o valor de alguma propriedade definida lá naquele arquivo application.properties no diretório resources.

Por exemplo, se o seu application.properties estiver assim:

```
db.senha-do-bd=12345
```

Você pode capturar o valor em uma variável

```
@Value("${db.senha-do-bd}")
private String senha;
```

aqui tem um tutorial mais completo:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

mas no geral, somente com esse trecho de código não dá pra saber o que está realmente acontecendo, você precisa entender o que cada anotação faz e o que seu código está fazendo.

Se quiser adicionar mais detalhes na pergunta, podemos te ajudar melhor.

Edit:
Talvez você possa apenas apagar essa variável provider, se ela não estiver sendo usada.

Comment: Excelente explicação Israel, atualizei a pergunta com um trecho maior, talvez facilite no entendimento. No caso todas variáveis que estão sendo usadas o Sonar pede uma notação, só não consegui identificar qual.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar algum trecho de código também? Pra saber em que contexto essas variáveis estão. Se você clicar alí em "why is this an issue?" pode ser útil também, geralmente ele te explica o motivo de ter feito esse apontamento

Comment: No caso, o trecho de códigos são usados dentro dos métodos... mas são muitos fica até inviável coloca-los aqui... mas na real só não entendi o por que de ser necessário essas notações em variáveis que estão sendo utilizados..

Comment: Imagino que você deva usar o `@Autowired`, mas você precisa verificar se a classe é um bean ou component do spring. Por exemplo, se dentro d classe CloseableHttpClient tiver a anotação `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Bean` em cima, você pode usar o `@Autowired` e uma instancia será injetada automaticamente pra você.

Comment: indico a leitura: https://blog.algaworks.com/injecao-de-dependencias-com-spring/

Comment: Essas classes em sua maioria são Entitys... por isso estou perdido hehe... Obrigado pela dica de leitura, irei ler.